# Bundle to be considered in the Dirac monopole

Tags: gauge-theory, magnetic-monopoles

When dealing with the Dirac magnetic monopole from the point of view of the gauge theory, most authors consider a principal bundle over $S^2$ under the pretext of being homotopic to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$. I do not understand why homotopy guarantees the invariance of such treatment.

Appreciate.

Comment: It's usually called a *principal bundle* in English. I don't know where your sphere  homotopy comes in here. The bundle for a minimal-charge  monople is pretty straightforward: $\pi: S^3 \to S^2$ where the bundle projection $\pi:E\to B$  from the total space $E=S^3$ to the base space $B=S^2$ in this instance is the *Hopf map*,

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is because when considering the bundle for electromagnetism, we have $(P, M, \pi, U(1))$, where $M$ is the spacetime. In the case of the magnetic monopole at the origin, space is $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$, then spacetime would be $M=(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\})\times \mathbb{R}$. Why do we consider the sphere as the base space to deal with it?

Comment: Because the radial coordinate is uninteresting as far as the monopole gauge  stuff goes. The key thing are the monopole harmonics which relace the ordinary spherical harmonics and are sections of the bundle with base space $S^2$. For the radial stuff you can look at Yamagishi's Phys.Rev.D 27 (1983) 2383-2396.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to take a look at this article. Thank you.